# Unexpected token '.' syntax error while using @nuxtjs/strapi module in nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I'm trying to use @nuxtjs/strapi module in my Nuxt.js application.
I've installed it with yarn command by using this command.

`yarn add @nuxtjs/strapi`

And I've changed the `nuxt.config.js` file

```
modules: [
  ...
  '@nuxtjs/strapi'
],
...
strapi: {
  url: process.env.STRAPI_URL || `http://localhost:1337/api`,
  entities: ['games'],
},
```

The thing is, I got this error just after change the `nuxt.config.js` file.

```
 FATAL  Unexpected token '.'                                                                                                                                                                   04:01:58

  at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                  │
   │                                       │
   │   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt-tower-of-hanoi@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt-tower-of-hanoi@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-22T19_01_58_618Z-debug.log
```

What is the best way to handle this issue?

PS: My nuxt version is 2.15.8 and @nuxtjs/strapi version is 1.3.1.

Npm version is 6.14.15 and Node version is 12.22.9.

Github link: https://github.com/Count-Monte/tower-of-hanoi

Comment: Do you have a github link?

Comment: Are you sure  `process.env.STRAPI_URL` is OK?  What is your node version?  NPM version?

Comment: @paulsm4, I'm sure process.env.STRAPI_URL is OK. And one more thing to mention is, when I remove the '@nuxtjs/strapi' from modules field, the error disappears.

Comment: @kissu, I've updated question with github link

Comment: @Count-Monte: thank you for telling us the Node and NPM versions - that helps.  NodeJS 12.22/NPM 6.14 should be "good" (although arguably 17.x/8.x might be "better").  I believe you that including nuxtjs/strapi in your project causes the problem ... but it doesn't tell us *WHY* the problem is occurring.  It could be "compatibility" (hence my asking about NodeJS and NPM versions).  It's probably *NOT* a "bug" in nuxtjs.  It's probably something a bit more subtle...  SUGGESTION: Consider deleting all the (local) modules from your NPM project folder, and recreating from scratch.

Comment: @paulsm4, thank you for your help. I've handled this! The thing is, I have used nvm and when I install @nuxtjs/strapi module my node version was 16.14.2 but when I'm trying to build the project it was 12.22.9. I've tried to change node version to 16.14.2 and it works! Thanks again with your kind help.